# Java Time Specific Average

Tags: java, time, average

I have a text file:

```
DATE 20090105
1 2.25 1.5
3 3.6 0.099
4 3.6 0.150
6 3.6 0.099
8 3.65 0.0499
DATE 20090105
DATE 20090106
1 2.4 1.40
2 3.0 0.5
5 3.3 0.19
7 2.75 0.5
10 2.75 0.25
DATE 20090106
DATE 20090107
2 3.0 0.5
2 3.3 0.19
9 2.75 0.5
DATE 20100107
```

On each day I have:

```
Time Rating Variance
```

I want to work out the average variance at a specific time on the biggest time scale.

The file is massive and this is just a small edited sample. This means I don't know the latest time and the earliest time (it's around 2600) and the latest time may be around 50000.

So for example on all the days I only have 1 value at time t=1, hence that is the average variance at that time.

At time t=2, on the first day, the variance at time t=2 takes value 1.5 as it last until t=3, on the second day it takes value=0.5 and on the third day it takes value ((0.5+0.18)/2). So the avg variance over all the days at time t=2 is the sum of all the variances at that time, divided by the number of different variances at that time.

For the last time in the day, the time scale it takes is t=1.

I'm just wondering as to how I would even go about this.

As a complete beginner I'm finding this quite complicated. I am a Uni Student, but university is finished and I am trying to learn Java to help out with my Dads business over the summer. So any help with regards to solutions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you're getting no answers because your problem description is difficult to understand. Please try to make this a little clearer to us mere mortals!

Comment: Also, what kind of output are you expecting? Do you want to write out a file with variations for every possible time? Or will you be querying for specific times and want to look up or compute the answers at that time?

Comment: On the 7th, your first time is 2. So what should your variance look like at time 1?

Comment: The variance at time 1 is 0 for the 7th, and this should contribute to the average, i.e for time t=1, the average would be (1.5+1.4+0)/3.

But,  during the day, if a variance is not declared at a specific time, this is because it still takes the last value in time for the variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got a code which works. But it takes a very long time(around 7 months worth of day, with 30,000 variances a day) because it has to loop round so many times. Are there any other better suggestions?

I mean this code, for something seemingly simple, would take around 24-28 hours...

package VarPackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadText {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String inputFileName="C:\\MFile";


    ArrayList<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileReader fr;
    BufferedReader br;

    // Time
    int t = 1;


    fr = new FileReader(inputFileName);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;


    while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
     fileLines.add(line);
    }

    AvgVar myVar = new AvgVar(fileLines);

    for(t=1; t<10; t++){ 
    System.out.print("Average Var at Time t=" + t + " = " + myVar.avgVar(t)+"\n");
```

}

}
}

===================================

## NewClass

package VarPackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AvgVar {
// Class Variables
private ArrayList inputData = new ArrayList();

// Constructor
    AvgVar(ArrayList fileData){
        inputData = fileData;
    }

```
public double avgVar(int time){

 double avgVar = 0;

 ArrayList<double[]> avgData = avgDuplicateVars(inputData);

 for(double[] arrVar : avgData){
 avgVar += arrVar[time-1];
 //System.out.print(arrVar[time-1] + "," + arrVar[time] + "," + arrVar[time+1] + "\n");
 //System.out.print(avgVar + "\n");
 }

 avgVar /= numDays(inputData);

 return avgVar;
}

private int numDays(ArrayList<String> varData){

 int n = 0;
 int flag = 0;
```

for(String line : varData){

```
String[] myData = line.split(" ");

if(myData[0].equals("DATE") && flag == 0){

    flag = 1;

   }
   else if(myData[0].equals("DATE") && flag == 1){

    n = n + 1;
    flag = 0;

   }
```

}

return n;

```
}

private ArrayList<double[]> avgDuplicateVars(ArrayList<String> varData){

 ArrayList<double[]> avgData = new ArrayList<double[]>();

 double[] varValue = new double[86400];
 double[] varCount = new double[86400];

 int n = 0;
 int flag = 0;
```

for(String iLine : varData){

```
String[] nLine = iLine.split(" ");
   if(nLine[0].equals("DATE") && flag == 0){

    for (int i=0; i<86400; i++){
    varCount[i] = 0;
    varValue[i] = 0;
    }

    flag = 1;

   }
   else if(nLine[0].equals("DATE") && flag == 1){

    for (int i=0; i<86400; i++){
    if (varCount[i] != 0){
    varValue[i] /= varCount[i];
    }
    }

    varValue = fillBlankSpreads(varValue, 86400);

    avgData.add(varValue.clone());

    flag = 0;

   }
   else{

    n = Integer.parseInt(nLine[0])-1;

    varValue[n] += Double.parseDouble(nLine[2]);
    varCount[n] += 1;

   }
```

}

return avgData;

```
}

private double[] fillBlankSpreads(double[] varValue, int numSpread){
//Filling the Data with zeros to make the code faster
 for (int i=1; i<numSpread; i++){
 if(varValue[i] == 0){
 varValue[i] = varValue[i-1];
 }
 }

 return varValue;
}
```

}

Comment: The problem arises in the for loop, where it goes through 86400 iterations for each second in the day.

I don't know, maybe an array of an array of an aray?

The coding is fine and gets me the correct answer as I said, but it doesnt get the me the right answer fast at well. So i tak e it slower

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow below steps

- Create a class with date and trv property
- Craete a list of above class
- Read the file using IO classes.
- Read in chunks and convert to string
- Split whole string by "DATE" and trim
- Split by space (" ")
- The first item would be your date.
- Convert all other items to float and find average.
- Add it to list. Now you have a list of daily average.
- You can persist it to disk and query it for your required data.

EDIT
you have edited your question and now it looks totaly diffrent. 
I think you need help in parsing the file. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think that's quite what I'm after.

I want the average at that specific time, over all the days. 

For Example.
MONDAY    People in store
9:00am    5
9:05am    10
9:10am    15
Tuesday
9:00am    1
9:05am    2   
9:10am    1

So an average model to predit how many people would be in the shop at these times is as below.

9:00am 3
9:05am 6
9:10am 8

As I have taken the average of the number of people in the store at that time. 

I think what you are describing is just the daily average?

Thanks

Comment: Then you need to parse the file and transfer the data to a database (ex mySQL). Then you can query it using your parameter

Comment: I literally have no idea, I've been doing Java for a week just trying to help out. I'm just trying to get this done as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are after a moving average that is calculated on a stream of data.
The following class I wrote provides some such statistics.

- moving average
- decaying average (reflects the average of the last few samples, based on the decay factor).
- moving variance
- decaying variance
- min and max.

Hope it helps.

```
/**
 * omry 
 * Jul 2, 2006
 * 
 * Calculates:
 * 1. running average 
 * 2. running standard deviation.
 * 3. minimum
 * 4. maximum
 */
public class Statistics
{
    private double m_lastValue;
    private double m_average = 0;
    private double m_stdDevSqr = 0;

    private int m_n = 0;
    private double m_max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    private double m_min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

    private double m_total;

    // decay factor.
    private double m_d;
    private double m_decayingAverage;
    private double m_decayingStdDevSqr;

    public Statistics()
    {
        this(2);
    }

    public Statistics(float d)
    {
        m_d = d;
    }

    public void addValue(double value)
    {
        m_lastValue = value;
        m_total += value;

        // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance
        m_n++;
        double delta = value - m_average;
        m_average = m_average + delta / (float)m_n;
        double md = (1/m_d);
        if (m_n == 1)
        {
            m_decayingAverage = value;
        }
        m_decayingAverage = (md * m_decayingAverage + (1-md)*value);

        // This expression uses the new value of mean
        m_stdDevSqr = m_stdDevSqr + delta*(value - m_average);

        m_decayingStdDevSqr = m_decayingStdDevSqr + delta*(value - m_decayingAverage);

        m_max = Math.max(m_max, value);
        m_min = Math.min(m_min, value);     
    }

    public double getAverage()
    {
        return round(m_average);
    }

    public double getDAverage()
    {
        return round(m_decayingAverage);
    }   

    public double getMin()
    {
        return m_min;
    }

    public double getMax()
    {
        return m_max;
    }

    public double getVariance()
    {
        if (m_n > 1)
        {
            return round(Math.sqrt(m_stdDevSqr/(m_n - 1)));
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }


    public double getDVariance()
    {
        if (m_n > 1)
        {
            return round(Math.sqrt(m_decayingStdDevSqr/(m_n - 1)));
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public int getN()
    {
        return m_n;
    }

    public double getLastValue()
    {
        return m_lastValue;
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        m_lastValue = 0;
        m_average = 0;
        m_stdDevSqr = 0;
        m_n = 0;
        m_max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        m_min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        m_decayingAverage = 0;
        m_decayingStdDevSqr = 0;
        m_total = 0;
    }

    public double getTotal()
    {
        return round(m_total);
    }

    private double round(double d)
    {
        return Math.round((d * 100))/100.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input and that is very useful and can help me learn about how to programme moving averages. 

However I am after an average AT a specific time. Not a moving average. 

But once again thank you, this will probably help me with my next task!

Comment: well, the average at a specific time is the value returned by getAverage() after you inserted all the values prior to that time.

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand. You want to

1. find the average variance at a given time `t` on each day - which is given by the highest timestamp on that day that is less than `t`
2. deal with cases where multiple readings at the same time by averaging them.
3. find the average variance on all days at time `t`

So I'd suggest, once you parse the data as @Manjoor suggested, then, (pseudocode!)

```
function getAverageAt(int t)
  float lastvariance = 0; // what value to start on, 
                        // if no variance is specified at t=1 on day 1
                        // also acts as accumulator if several values at one 
                        // timestamp
  float allDaysTotal = 0; // cumulative sum of the variance at time t for all days
  for each day {
    float time[], rating[], variance[];
    //read these from table
    int found=0; //how many values found at time t today
    for(int i=0;i<time.length;i++){
       if(time[i]<t) lastvariance=variance[i];  // find the most recent value
                        // before t.
                        // This relies on your data being in order!
       else if(time[i]==t){  // time 
         found++;
         if (found==1) lastvariance=variance[i]; // no previous occurrences today
         else lastvariance+=variance[i];
       }
       else if(time[i]>t) break;
    }
    if(found>1) lastvariance/=found;  // calculate average of several simultaneous
    // readings, if more than one value found today at time t.
    // Note that: if found==0, this means you're using a previous
    // timestamp's value.
    // Also note that, if at t=1 you have 2 values of variance, that 
    // averaged value will not continue over to time t. 
    // You could easily reimplement that if that's the behaviour you desire,
    // the code is similar, but putting the time<t condition along with the 
    // time==t condition 
    allDaysTotal+=lastvariance;
  }
  allDaysMean = allDaysTotal / nDays
```

Your problem isn't a simple one, as the catch-cases I pointed out show.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know what parsing is, but I'm sure I'll be able to find it out.

is this fairly complicated then? I mean after a week of coding, should i be able to do this?

Comment: Also what do you mean by the highest timestamp that is less than t?

My variances will take values between 1 & 10, with the final variance at 10 carrying on for one second till 11.

So for an average variance at time t=3, I would take all the variances at time t=3 across all the days, and if there isnt a specified value at time t=3, then that means it takes the previous available time's variance as its own variance.

Comment: yes. the 'timestamp' of each data point is the first column of your data. So 'the highest timestamp on that day that is less than t' is a more computer-friendly way of writing what you just said. Parsing, in your case, is turning text into tables of numbers. The task isn't complicated if you follow the steps I've said, but you need to consider the catch-cases like when the last recorded point in time was itself an average of several data points. I mean, if you strip my code down, you could get it to 10 lines of code!

Comment: Hi Sanjay, what do you think of the code Ive written?

It's very slow but it works...